# need some php function to remove slashes

Tags: php, strip

My original string look like this .

```
25\\\" height x 12\\\" width x 9\\\
```

but i want to remove these slashes from the sting like the below text.

I used stripslashes function , but gives only 25 .

`25" height x 12" width x 9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[StripSlashes](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.stripslashes.php)

Good for this or str_replace

Comment: i tried strip slashed but i am getting some errors with strip slashes

Comment: Just tried `<?php
$string = '25\\" height x 12\\" width x 9\\';
echo stripslashes($string);
?>`. and it is giving me correct result.

Comment: i am so sorry the actual problem was i using this string, in html.

eg:value="<?php stripslashes("25\\" height x 12\\" width x 9\\")?>".

and now i tried value with single quotes i works.

Thanks for all .....

Answer (score 4):

You make it sound like you have double slashes added. Here is a quick block of code that tests a few different cases. And in 3/4 of the var_dumps it prints the data correctly. The extra slashes are to escape string encoding. Hopefully if you play around with the code below, it will help figure out the problem in your string.

```
<?php

$s = "25\\\\\" height x 12\\\\\" width x 9\\\\";

var_dump(stripslashes($s));
var_dump(stripslashes(stripslashes($s)));

$s = "25\\\" height x 12\\\" width x 9\\";

var_dump(stripslashes($s));
var_dump(stripslashes(stripslashes($s)));

?>
```

Comment: i am so sorry the actual problem was i using this string, in html.

eg:value="<?php stripslashes("25\\" height x 12\\" width x 9\\")?>".

and now i tried value with single quotes i works.

Thanks for all .....

Comment: You should do always wrap your values in htmlentities, like this: <?php echo htmlentities("I am a dangerous <script>"); ?>. This will make sure any quotes, slashes, and HTML tags do not get printed as such. Quotes have special meanings inside of tags, especially your html input boxes with value (the quote was closing the value attribute). Therefore in your case you needed <?php echo htmlentities(stripslashes($string)); ?>. The quotes will then get turned into the special &quot; HTML entity.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use str_replace like this

```
$str='25\\\" height x 12\\\" width x 9\\\""';
echo(str_replace("\\", ' ',$str));
```

Answer (score 1):

Please used  stripslashes  function. I used  and i got the following result:

echo stripslashes ('25\\" height x 12\\" width x 9\\');

output: 25" height x 12" width x 9